# A dotfile that will set the default node version on a project using nvm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, version-control, nvm

In ruby when using rbenv you can make a `.ruby-version` file and put it in the local directory. https://gist.github.com/fnichol/1912050 
I'm looking for something similar to this using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)?

**Question:**

Is there a property to set in package.json or a file to create that will set the default version of node of a project?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do this with a combination of NVM, dotfiles in your project directory, and a little tool called `direnv` which allows you to load in environment variables on a per-directory basis.

http://direnv.net/

Install NVM and direnv, and then `cd` to the directory you want to change Node versions in.

Add a file called `.nvmrc` in that directory, containing just the version number of the Node version you want to auto-switch to, e.g.,:

```
6.2.2
```

Then add an environment configuration file called `.envrc` to your directory, containing this script:

```
nvmrc=~/.nvm/nvm.sh
if [ -e $nvmrc ]; then
  source $nvmrc
  nvm use
fi

PATH_add node_modules/.bin
```

If you now `cd` out of this directory, and then `cd` back in, direnv will kick in and you should be asked to add the directory to your direnv whitelist by typing `direnv allow .` at the prompt. Once whitelisted, direnv will auto-run that script whenever you enter this directory, setting your Node version to the version number in `.nvmrc`.

As a bonus, it will also add the `node_modules` directory to your PATH, so you can execute binaries from those directories without prepending the `node_modules` path.

Comment: The great thing about direnv is that it automatically undoes all its modifications when you change out of the directory (eg: to a different project).  This answer doesn't support undoing the effect of `nvm use` when direnv unloads.

Comment: To add to Ross' answer, you can use `asdf` instead of `nvm` which works very similar to nvm but does more than just nodejs. See [asdf-nodejs](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs) and [asdf-vm](https://github.com/asdf-vm)

The combination of `asdf` and `direnv` works magic

Comment: `node -v > .nvmrc` will create the file in one go

Answer (score 8):

There is now some native support for this built into direnv's stdlib. It's documented in their [wiki](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/Node), but the [source](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/blob/75886a2644ab8b679f5253c129ef03453524ff70/stdlib.sh#L478-L557) is just as easy to read, or type `direnv stdlib` to find it).

```
$ node -v
v8.0.0
$ cat .node-version
4.3.2
$ cat .envrc
use node
$ export NODE_VERSIONS=~/.nvm/versions/node
$ export NODE_VERSION_PREFIX=v
$ direnv allow
direnv: loading ~/.config/direnv/direnvrc
direnv: loading .envrc
direnv: using node
direnv: Successfully loaded NodeJS v4.3.2 (via .node-version), from prefix (~/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3.2)
direnv: export +CPATH +LD_LIBRARY_PATH +LIBRARY_PATH +PKG_CONFIG_PATH ~MANPATH ~PATH
$ node -v
v4.3.2
$ direnv deny
direnv: error .envrc is blocked. Run `direnv allow` to approve its content.
$ node -v
v8.0.0
```

If you want `node_modules/.bin` in your path, just add the line `layout node` to your `.envrc` (the [source](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/blob/75886a2644ab8b679f5253c129ef03453524ff70/stdlib.sh#L340-L345) is also in `direnv stdlib` output).

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I do it, generally similar to Ross Shannon's answer, with a few differences:

1. You can specify the Node version in just the `package.json`, without requiring an `.nvmrc` file
2. You can also specify the Node version directly in the `.envrc`, again without an `.nvmrc` file
3. I don't add `node_modules/.bin` to the PATH, but if that's your preferred behavior, just add `PATH_add node_modules/.bin` to the `use_nvm` function.

For me, supporting Node version selection from `package.json` rather than `.nvmrc` was important because I didn't want to worry about keeping two files in sync (especially on a project with multiple collaborators). That said, this solution still works with `.nvmrc`.

This solution requires [direnv](https://direnv.net), [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) and optionally (if you want to be able to select the Node version from package.json) [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

In `~/.config/direnv/direnvrc` file, add the following:

```
# To use:
# 1) Node version specified in package.json, in .envrc add:
#      use nvm package.json
#    This requires that package.json contains something like
#      "engines": {
#        "node": ">=6.9.2"
#      },
#
# 2) Node version specified in .envrc add:
#      use nvm 6.9.2
#
# 3) Node version specified in .nvmrc, in .envrc add:
#      use nvm
use_nvm() {
  local node_version=$1

  if [[ $node_version = "package.json" ]]; then
    if has jq; then
      node_version=$(jq --raw-output .engines.node package.json | tr -d "<=> ")
    else
      echo "Parsing package.json for node version to use with direnv requires jq"
    fi
  fi

  nvm_sh=~/.nvm/nvm.sh
  if [[ -e $nvm_sh ]]; then
    source $nvm_sh
    nvm use $node_version
  fi
}
```

In your project directory, add an `.envrc` file that calls `use nvm`, e.g.:

```
use nvm package.json
```

However, I prefer something like the following for my `.envrc`:

```
if declare -Ff use_nvm >/dev/null; then
  use nvm package.json
fi
```

for shared projects with a shared `.envrc` so that collaborators who don't have `use nvm` defined don't get an error.

Now, when you enter your project directory, your desired Node version will be automatically used (the first time, you'll be prompted to whitelist your changes to `.envrc` with `direnv allow`).

Comment: Thank you lots for the answer, this is perfect!
I use nvm and I couldn't bother setting up a different default node version for my whole system, but when I need to run something most of the time I need a newer version of node than my system's, so I simply decided to use a `.envrc` in my home folder, but then no nvm integration, until I found this. 
Now I can just put `use nvm default` in my `~/.envrc` and I have automatic node version when I need :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Note: This solution does not switch the folder version automatically.

Other answers were not that helpful to me, and hence, this is the solution I followed:

Create a `.nvmrc` file and specify the node version you expect your app to run on.

```
touch .nvmrc
```

Open the file and specify the version, say `13.3.0`

Post you define a version in `.nvmrc`, you can alternatively also define the `engines` in the `package.json` file, which will ensure that the version meets the requirements, if it doesn't, running `npm install` will fail.

```
"engineStrict": true,
"engines": {
  "node": "13.3.0"
}
```

Below is the error you'll encounter if it fails to match the node version.

[image: Source: My Project]

Lastly, to ensure that it switches to the right node version, you can either run the following command post navigating to the directory.

```
nvm use
```

And this will switch to the desired version, or you can add it to one of the `script` command in `package.json` like:

```
"scripts": { 
  /*
   * here, the second command (nodemon server.js) will change base on the dev 
   * server you are using and the path where you've server.js
  */
  "dev:app:run": "nvm use; nodemon server.js"
},
```

The above will switch the node version before it starts the server.

Comment: Thanks for you tips, very helpful :) Just a side note that from Node 18.11 onward nodemon isn't as needed now since that functionality is included in Node via `node --watch` with no extra modules.